# Bootstrap 4 grid layout problem migrating from Boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

using bootstrap 3.3.7 i was able to "row span" a div for multiple rows and fill the remaining columns space  with other divs, for example using this code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Bootstrap 3.3.7</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding:0px">
      <div  style="background-color:green">level 1 - col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6</div>
      <div  style="background-color:green">level 2 - col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6</div>
      <div  style="background-color:green">level 3 - col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6</div>
      <div  style="background-color:green">level 4 - col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6</div>
      <div  style="background-color:green">level 5 - col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

i was getting :
[Bootstrap 3.3.7 example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaSht.png)

But using  Bootstrap 4.1.1 i get this:

[Bootstrap 4.1.1 example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYht.png)

Only the first two divs fill the remaining 6 columns and the rest of them shifts under the first div, i tried to look at the documentation but i couldn't fiugure this out, is anyone able to replicate the first behavior on boostrap 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap-4, as it's using `flex,` you need to provide containing columns and rows to define relationship between everything. If you want the ten col-3 sections to be together, then put them into their own col-6 container, and then create a new row to hold the smaller columns (which are now col-6 because they're starting the 12 unites over again).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
        <h1>Responsive Bootstrap 4.6.0</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="padding:0px">
                <div style="background-color:green">level 1 - col-6</div>
                <div style="background-color:green">level 2 - col-6</div>
                <div style="background-color:green">level 3 - col-6</div>
                <div style="background-color:green">level 4 - col-6</div>
                <div style="background-color:green">level 5 - col-6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 p-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue">Span 3 - col 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, you don't need to define the columns at every breakpoint. Specifying `col-6` will provide a six column span from a smartphone display up to a wide screen monitor. You only need to add a `col-lg-3` if you want a different column setup for a larger screen (start from the small screen and work up).